# error: ILINING failed in call to ALWAYS_INLINE ‘unsigned INT _tzcnt_u32(unsigned INT)’: target specific option mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cmake, inlining, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to compile this project (https://github.com/speedskater/hot) which is implemented in C++, IM trying to compile it using an oracle virtual machine, the CMAKE flags are as follows:
[CMAKE FLAGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e8HG.png)

meanwhile while trying to compile I keep getting this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaemR.png)
(error: ILINING failed in call to ALWAYS_INLINE ‘unsigned INT _tzcnt_u32(unsigned INT)’: target specific option mismatch)

some other answers suggested the -march=native, but its already included here,

can someone explain to me whether I should change the flags or do something else, thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages **images** with textual representation of code or error message: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question. Instead, paste the code into the question post as **text**. After pasting you could use corresponding formatting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.